# Optimal stopping of Levy processes

Tags: markov-process, stopping-times, levy-processes

I have problems to understand the proof of Lemma 1 in the paper "Optimal Stopping for Levy Processes with one-sided Solutions" by Ernesto Mordecki and Yuliya Mishura:

Consider a Levy process $X$, $M=\sup\{X_t:t\geq 0\}$ which is assumed to be a proper random variable, a discount rate $r\geq 0$, integrable $g:\mathbb{R}\to[0,\infty)$ with $lim_{x\to -\infty}g(x)=0$, $x^*\in\mathbb{R}$, $G^*:[x^+,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ measurable and nondecreasing with $E_x(G^*(M))=g(x)$ for all $x\geq x^*$ and $G$ is defined by 
$$
G(x)=
\begin{cases}
G^*(x), & \text{ if }x\geq x^*\\
0, & \text{ if }x<x^*
\end{cases}
$$
and for every $a\geq x^*$ we have the stopping time $\tau_a=\inf\{t:X_t\geq a\}$.

Then we have for any $a\geq x^*$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
E_x(G(M)1_{\{M\geq a\}})=E_x(e^{-r\tau_a}g(X_{\tau_a}1_{\{\tau^+<\infty\}})).
$$
Proof.

Taking conditional expectation w.r.t. the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_a}$ and applying the iterated law of conditional expectation, we have
$$
E_x(G(M)1_{\{M\geq a\}})
\stackrel{(1)}{=}E_x(G(\sup_{0\leq t<\infty}X_t)1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}})
$$
$$
\stackrel{(2)}{=}E_x(G(X_{\tau_a}+\sup_{\tau_a\leq t<\infty}(X_t-X_{\tau_a})1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}})
$$
$$
\stackrel{(3)}{=}E_x(E_{X_{\tau_a}}(G(X_{\tau_a}+\sup_{0\leq s<\infty}X_s)1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}}))
$$
$$
\stackrel{(4)}{=}E_x(g(X_{\tau_a})1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}})
$$
I don't understand step (3) and (4). In step three it seems that the Markov property is beeing used but I couln't find any theorem that would justify this step. In step (4) it seems to me that there is an $X_{\tau_a}$ too much. I hope anyone can explain at least step (3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the following statement:

> Let $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Lévy process and $\tau$ a finite stopping time. Then the process $$Y_t := X_{t+\tau}-X_{\tau}$$ is a Lévy process which equals in distribution $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$. Moreover, $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ are independent.

Back to your framework: If we define $Y_t := X_{\tau_a+t}-X_{\tau_a}$, then

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}_x \bigg[ G \bigg( X_{\tau_a} + \sup_{\tau_a \leq t < \infty} (X_t-X_{\tau_a}) \bigg) 1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}} \bigg] &= \mathbb{E}_x \big[ G(X_{\tau_a}+\sup_{t \geq 0} Y_t) 1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}} \big] \\ &= \mathbb{E} \big[ G(x+X_{\tau_a}+\sup_{t \geq 0} Y_t) 1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}} \big]\end{align*}.$$

Now we use the tower property and condition on $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_a}$, i.e. we use that

$$\mathbb{E}(\dots) = \mathbb{E} \bigg( \mathbb{E}( \dots \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau_a}) \bigg).$$

This gives

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}_x \bigg[ G \bigg( X_{\tau_a} + \sup_{\tau_a \leq t < \infty} (X_t-X_{\tau_a}) \bigg) \bigg] &= \mathbb{E} \bigg[ 1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}} \mathbb{E} \big( G(x+X_{\tau_a}+\sup_{t \geq 0} Y_t) \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau_a} \big) \bigg] \\ &= \mathbb{E} \bigg[ 1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}} \mathbb{E} \big( G(y+\sup_{t \geq 0} Y_t) \big) \big|_{y=x+X_{\tau_a}} \bigg] \\ &=  \mathbb{E}_x \bigg[ 1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}} \mathbb{E} \big( G(y+\sup_{t \geq 0} Y_t) \big) \big|_{y=X_{\tau_a}} \bigg] \end{align*}$$

where we have used in the penultimate step that $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_a}$ are independent and that $X_{\tau_a}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\tau_a}$-measurable. Since Lévy processes are space homogeneous, we have

$$\mathbb{E} \big( G(y+ \sup_{t \geq 0} Y_t) \big) = \mathbb{E}_y(G(\sup_{t \geq 0} Y_t)) = g(y)$$

for all $y \geq x^*$; the last "=" follows from the fact that $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has the same distribution as $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$. Consequently,

$$\mathbb{E}_x \bigg[ G \bigg( X_{\tau_a} + \sup_{\tau_a \leq t < \infty} (X_t-X_{\tau_a}) \bigg) \bigg] = \mathbb{E}_x(g(X_{\tau_a}) 1_{\{\tau_a<\infty\}}).$$

Comment: Dear saz, I have problems to understand the tower property here. As I understand it $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectation induced by some given probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ and according the notations from my lecture notes $\mathbb{E}_x$ is the expextation induced by some other probability measure $\mathbb{P}_x$. But as I know the tower property, it only works with the same probability measure. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: @AlexanderBorchert Sorry; I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Could you explain what it exactly means that a process is space homogeneous?

Comment: @AlexanderBorchert By space-homogeneity of a Lévy process $(L_t)_t$, I mean that $$\mathbb{E}^x f(L_t) = \mathbb{E} f(x+L_t)$$ with the convention that $\mathbb{E} = \mathbb{E}^0$.

Comment: Is that true for every measurable $f$ or only those which are bounded or nonnegative?

Comment: @AlexanderBorchert For any $f$ such that $f(L_t)$ is integrable. What I'm trying to say is that a Lévy process $(L_t^{(x)})_{t \geq 0}$ started at some point $X_0^{(x)}=x$ is nothing else but the shifted process started at $0$, i.e. $L_t^{(x)} = x + L_t^{(0)}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explenation. Untuitevely the property is clear to me. I just have problems to see how it is derived from the definition of my lecture notes. I will ask about this on a seperate post.

Comment: It seems that in the step $\mathbb{E}_x[G(X_{\tau_a}+\sup_{t\geq 0}Y_t)1_{\tau_a<\infty}] = \mathbb{E}[G(x+X_{\tau_a}+\sup_{t\geq 0}Y_t)1_{\tau_a<\infty}]$ you are using a more general property than $\mathbb{E}_xf(X_t)=\mathbb{E}f(x+X_t)$. Could you explain what you are using here?

Comment: It seems that you are using that $\sup_{t\geq 0}Y_t\stackrel{d}{=}\sup_{t\geq 0}X_t$. Could you explain to me why this holds? In general this doesn't hold for processes with the same fdd's or? (fdd is finite dimensional distribution)

Comment: @drogan We have $\sup_{t \in I} Y_t \stackrel{d}{=} \sup_{t \in I} X_t$ for any finite set $I \subseteq [0,\infty)$. Choose an enumeration $(t_n)_n$ of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,\infty)$, then we have $$\sup_{i=1,\ldots,n} X_{t_i} \stackrel{d}{=} \sup_{i=1,\ldots,n} Y_{t_i}.$$ Using e.g. that any distribution can be  uniquely characterized by its characteristic function and the dominated convergence theorem, this implies $$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_{t_n} \stackrel{d}{=} \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} Y_{t_n}.$$ Finally, note that both $(X_t)_t$ and $(Y_t)_t$ are cadlag and therefore the previous identity

Comment: ...already implies $\sup_{t \geq 0} X_t \stackrel{d}{=} \sup_{t \geq 0} Y_t$. (There is no reason why the distributions should not be the same... note that both Lévy processes have the same characteristic exponent and therefore, from a distributional point of view, we can't distinguish $(X_t)_t$ from $(Y_t)_t$.)